# modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly, or modelBuilder.Configurations.Add

Tags: entity-framework, reflection

I have an EF `DBContext` in the same assembly as my models and mappings (using database-first).

Previously, we have explicitly added each mapping into the context in the `OnModelCreating` method, but this is tedious and error-prone, if someone adds a table and mapping, but forgets to add it to the context in this way.

We would be writing something like this:
`modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TableMap());`

It seems that the alternative is to simply use something like the following:
`modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

This seems to work fine, but my concern is that this must now be using reflection to get all the types that inherit from `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>`.

The EF context is being used by a RESTful web API, so my concern is that this code could run often if contexts are getting frequently created and destroyed by heavy API use.
I've been taught to avoid reflection if at all possible because of performance costs. Does this method of adding the entity mappings into the context come with any appreciable performance hit as a result of using reflection? If so, will the hit increase as the number of classes in the assembly goes up? Should I stick with explicitly adding all the entity configurations into the context?

Comment: _"Does this method of adding the entity mappings into the context come with any appreciable performance hit as a result of using reflection?"_ -  [measure it](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: @CodeCaster Currently, there is no noticeable hit from doing it this way, but the context only contains a handful of tables a this point in development, and as it is in development, the API won't be getting any load testing until complete, which is some way down the line. 
I'd like to find out now, rather than creating a maintenance headache for later. In other words, I won't be able to get an answer as to how this scales, without scaling it, what I measure now won't give me an accurate reflection of how this will be used in practice, hence this question...

Comment: It would depend on so many variables that you're the only one who can say anything about this. I'd also start load testing sooner than only when the product is finished.